# Reusing ObjectMapper model for multiple mapping

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

Hi i am using **ObjectMapper** for my Json mapping and i have a model class named People which has one property personName and i am doing the mapping like this

```
class People : Mappable,BaseMappable{
    var personName : String?
    required init(map:Map){ }
    func mapping(map: Map){
        personName <- map["name"]
    }
}
```

but my problem is that i am reusing this model for more then one `websservice` and `personName` might come for different keys. In my current example i am mapping `personName` using name key but in my other `webservice` response `personName` should get initialised using `userName` key so how do i manage one variable managing for multiple keys?

Comment: Ask API guy to change it to `name` key.

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered this problem many times, and there is no elegant solution.

Best solution I've found is to just change the API to keep everything consistent, but failing that, one method is to set the variable twice:

```
personName <- map["name"]
if personName == nil {
    personName <- map["personName"]
}
```